# How to compare keys in yaml files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, compare, yaml

There are two ruby on rails internationalization yaml files. One file is complete and another one is with missing keys. How can I compare two yaml files and see missing keys in second file? Are there any tools for doing that?

Comment: Would you just want to load the YAML files and iterate through the values? Seems easy enough, just wonder if there is something I am missing.

Comment: I was thinking maybe there is already made tool for this task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming `file1` is the proper version and `file2` is the version with missing keys:

```rb
def compare_yaml_hash(cf1, cf2, context = [])
  cf1.each do |key, value|

    unless cf2.key?(key)
      puts "Missing key : #{key} in path #{context.join(".")}" 
      next
    end

    value2 = cf2[key]
    if (value.class != value2.class)
      puts "Key value type mismatch : #{key} in path #{context.join(".")}" 
      next
    end

    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      compare_yaml_hash(value, value2, (context + [key]))  
      next
    end
      
    if (value != value2)
      puts "Key value mismatch : #{key} in path #{context.join(".")}" 
    end    
  end
end
```

Now

```rb
compare_yaml_hash(YAML.load_file("file1"), YAML.load_file("file2"))
```

Limitation: Current implementation should be extended to support arrays if your YAML file contains arrays.

Comment: This also fails if you are comparing two normale locale files. Remove the language prefix at the top of the files before comparing them to fix this.

Comment: @d-Pixie - to compare locale files: `rails console; I18n.translate(:foo); en = I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en]; de = I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:de]; compare_yaml_hash(en, de, [])`. The `translate(:foo)` is to force it to load translations. With the shown function, there will be lots of "key value mismatch" for different languages; comment that line if you only care about missing keys. Also run it in the other direction.

Comment: Actually, scratch using `I18n.backend` - it may have keys which are not in the files you want to compare.

Comment: @NathanLong Yeah, I18n is a bit tricky when it comes to that ;) Good general idéa though. It'll work if you only have one translation file or if you want to compare the entire locales anyway. Also good spot on the "key value mismatch", that's a bit irritating when you only need the keys... There is also the `I18n.backend.send(:init_translations)` for forcing I18n to initialize, instead of `I18n.translate(:foo)`, YMMW.

Comment: @Harish shetty..the above code is good but i need the same code to compare 2 yaml files and fill default parameters where keys are missing in python.Can you please give a suggestion here..i am not getting how to write function for this in a class in python lang

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a fast tool to do that. I decided to write my [own tool for this.](https://github.com/acatton/yamlkeysdiff)

You can install it with cabal:

```
$ cabal update
$ cabal install yamlkeysdiff
```

Then you can diff two files this way:

```
$ yamlkeysdiff file1.yml file2.yml
> missing key in file2
< missing key in file1
```

You can also compare two subsets of the files:

```
$ yamlkeysdiff "file1.yml#key:subkey" "file2.yml#otherkey"
```

It behaves exactly like `diff`, you can do this:

```
$ yamlkeysdiff file1.yml file2.yml && echo Is the same || echo Is different
```

Comment: Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: yamlkeysdiff-0.5.1 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of yamlkeysdiff-0.5.1)
rejecting: base-4.8.2.0/installed-0d6... (conflict: yamlkeysdiff => base>=4.6
&& <4.8)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, 4.9.1.0, 4.9.0.0, 4.8.2.0, 4.8.1.0, 4.8.0.0,
4.7.0.2, 4.7.0.1, 4.7.0.0, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0,
4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0,
3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed instance)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Answer (score 1):

**[differz](https://github.com/heel/differz)** compares two YAML files and prints missing keys in the second file.

```
differz show file1.yml file2.yml
```

It comes both as a library and as a command-line tool. You can install the latter with `gem install differz`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to extract the diff to have something to work with, and the snippet here just prints stuff. So my version returns a hash with diff. It's structure mirrors the original hashes, but the values are descriptions of the differences.

```
def deep_hash_diff(hash1, hash2, hash1_name = 'Hash 1', hash2_name = 'Hash 2')
  diff = {}
  (hash1.keys - hash2.keys).each do |key1|
    diff[key1] = "Present in #{hash1_name}, but not in #{hash2_name}"
  end
  (hash2.keys - hash1.keys).each do |key2|
    diff[key2] = "Present in #{hash2_name}, but not in #{hash1_name}"
  end

  (hash1.keys & hash2.keys).each do |common_key|
    if hash1[common_key].is_a?(Hash)
      if hash2[common_key].is_a?(Hash)
        res = deep_hash_diff(hash1[common_key], hash2[common_key], hash1_name, hash2_name)
        diff[common_key] = res if res.present?
      else
        diff[common_key] = "#{hash1_name} has nested hash, but #{hash2_name} just value #{hash2[common_key]}"
      end
    elsif hash2[common_key].is_a?(Hash)
      diff[common_key] = "#{hash2_name} has nested hash, but #{hash1_name} just value #{hash1[common_key]}"
    end
  end
  diff
end
```

I've then used it pretty much as:

```
res = deep_hash_diff(YAML.load_file("en.yml"), YAML.load_file("spa.yml"), 'English translation', 'Spanish translation')
puts(res.to_yaml) # for nicer output
```