# How to compare the keys and the content of a yaml-file in Java?

Tags: java, spring, yaml, string-comparison, snakeyaml

I want to find a framework, 
which is able to compare the content of two yaml-files.

I found a link, how they describe it in ruby. 
[How to compare keys in yaml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274126/how-to-compare-keys-in-yaml-files)

But I am searching for a Java-Framework for it.

It would be nice, if the result can be shown like a "git diff" command.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare by using [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) and jackson-yaml...

add below dependency:

```
implementation 'com.flipkart.zjsonpatch:zjsonpatch:0.4.10'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.9.8'
```

Try with this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.flipkart.zjsonpatch.JsonDiff;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        JsonNode file1 = objectMapper.readTree(new File("/your/file/path/file1.yml"));
        JsonNode file2 = objectMapper.readTree(new File("/your/file/path/file2.yml"));
        JsonNode patch = JsonDiff.asJson(file1, file2);
        String diffs = patch.toString();
        System.out.println(diffs);
    }
}
```